# Micronaut Swagger multimodule

Tags: maven, swagger, micronaut

I am trying to visualize the API definitions from a Multimodule project. First I want to start from simple, and I want to visualize the yaml from the parent module. Then I will add other APIs in my Swagger Controller to call the specific url as is done in the example https://github.com/frehov/micronaut-swagger-server

I have my Swagger Controller and my SwaggerConfiguration with my index.hbs inside resource > views.swagger I took the example from the repo https://github.com/frehov/micronaut-swagger-server

This is my Result:

[image]

Instead of something like:

[image]

When I compared the two project, somehow my view.swagger package from my target folder gets generated into a different way, compared with the example:

[image]

What I am missing?
Could you please look at my repo:

https://github.com/amhg/swagger

Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The folder containing the swagger-ui-wrapper (index.hbs) in your project is called 'views.swagger', while the sample has defined 'views/swagger' (so swagger is a folder inside of views). Change that and you get the views/swagger result in your target.

You also need to enable the micronaut handlebars-views (i.e. serving the .hbs files from a controller); add these to the pom.xml of startup (not at the root-pom!):

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
      <artifactId>micronaut-views</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.github.jknack</groupId>
      <artifactId>handlebars</artifactId>
      <version>4.1.0</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```

These will perform the magic of rendering the configuration you return from the controller into an html-page.
Depending on where you're going to put the swagger-annotated controllers, you might also want to add

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
      <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
      <version>${swagger.version}</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: I am not sure if that will be the main reason, I have added another image, the folder structure comes as soon as I run mvn clean install. I still get the same result page from localhost:8080/api

Comment: Sorry, thought you were only blocked by the folder-name problem; I've added instructions to enable handlerbar-views

Comment: Thank you, now is correct the folder structure "views/swagger". I have added swagger dependency in the "startup" project. However I am not able to get the swagger view, I still get the same result. Could you please look at my changes,  https://github.com/amhg/swagger.git

Comment: Before localhost:8080/api returned a json and now it returns a swagger-ui page (I cloned and ran the git-branch to verify). What do you mean by "same result"?

Comment: As same result I mean, only the json (no swagger-ui) . The image I added at the beginning: "This is my result"

Comment: Thank you for your help. The next step is to show the api from account, so I will let you know ;)

Comment: if you have sometime, could you please have a look at my post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66438057/micronaut-swagger-multimodule-call-specific-module-swagger-ui Thank you!

Comment: Hi @BartRobeyns I still can't make it, showing the API spec from another module, could you please help me. I have tried with another endpoint @Get("/{url}") http://localhost:8080/api/account Repo https://github.com/amhg/swagger